# Two-layer RAII to support a critical section

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, winapi, raii

For the code, if one considers using RAII to encapsulate `CriticalSection` (global scope), two RAII layers are needed: `InitializeCriticalSection` layer (main function scope), enter `EnterCriticalSection` layer (multi-thread based Proc scope).

```
// Global variable
CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection; 

int main( void )
{
    // Initialize the critical section one time only.
    if (!InitializeCriticalSection(&CriticalSection) ) 
        return;
    ...

    // Release resources used by the critical section object.
    DeleteCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID lpParameter )
{
    // Request ownership of the critical section.
    EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection); 

    // Access the shared resource.

    // Release ownership of the critical section.
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

    return 1;
}
```

As `CriticalSection` and the two layers all have different scopes, and also enter `InitializeCriticalSection` layer must be on top of `EnterCriticalSection` layer.

```
class CriticalSectionGuard {
public:
    CriticalSectionGuard(CRITICAL_SECTION * cs) : m_CS(cs) {
        InitializeCriticalSection(m_CS);
    }
    ~CriticalSectionGuard() {
        DeleteCriticalSection(m_CS);
    }
    void lock() {
        EnterCriticalSection(m_CS);
    }
    void unlock{
        LeaveCriticalSection(m_CS);
    }
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION * m_CS;
}

class GetLock {
public:
    GetLock(CriticalSectionGuard* plock) : m_csg(plock) {
        m_csg->lock();
    }
    ~GetLock(void) {
        m_csg->unlock();
    }
private:
    CriticalSectionGuard * m_csg;
};



// Global variable
CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection;

int main(void)
{
    // Initialize the critical section one time only.
    CriticalSectionGuard CSG(&CriticalSection);
    ...
}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    // we need pass along the CSG Pointer, which is messy.
    GetLock(&CSG);
    ...

        return 1;
}
```

It looks quite bad, as the `CriticalSectionGuard` object is not in the global scope, it need pass along to threads.

Please share any suggestions or criticisms to improve the code.

Answer (score 5):

We can simplify that a lot.

You are not really using RAII on the `CriticalSection` as you declare it in one place then initialize it in another. But `CRITICAL_SECTION` is a type as you pass a pointer around.

Why not simplify a bit:

```
class GetLock;
class CriticalSection {
public:
    CriticalSection() {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&m_CS); // get a pointer to the member
    }
    ~CriticalSection() {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&m_CS);
    }
private:
    friend class GetLock;   // Only GetLock should be locking/unlocking this object.
    void lock() {
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_CS);
    }
    void unlock{
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_CS);
    }
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION    m_CS;   // Make this a member
                                // Now make the constructor initialize it.
}
```

Now its use case becomes.

```
CriticalSection  criticalSection;

int main() {
    // Critical section variable already up and running.
}
```

If we look at the GetLock.
I would not passes pointers as parameters. This means people can accidentally pass a `nullptr` and thus cause your code to break. Always pass by reference if you have to have parameter there.

```
class GetLock {
public:
    // Pass a reference to the CriticalSection
    GetLock(CriticalSection& plock)
        : m_csg(plock)
    {
        m_csg.lock();
    }
    ~GetLock(void) {
        m_csg.unlock();
    }
private:
    CriticalSectionGuard& m_csg;   // Keep a reference to the critical section.
};
```

Now this can be used like:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    GetLock lock(criticalSection);

    return 1;
}
```

Note the difference above to your version:

```
    GetLock(&CSG);   // This creates a temporary object.
                     // This object is destroyed at the end of the
                     // statement (which is the ;).
                     // This mean you call lock() and unlock() before
                     // the end of the line.
```

I should also note that using global variables is considered bad practice. You should try and design your program so that you pass the things being manipulated around as parameters (or part of an object). I can't really suggest an improvement with knowing more about the code.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. What if you put 'CriticalSection  criticalSection;' in main(maybe some other functions you need a new criticalSection), then how to call GetLock in thread proc, if you do not pass the pointer along.

Comment: `what if you put 'CriticalSection criticalSection;' in main(` Then you pass a reference to the critical section as a parameter to that piece of code. That also makes that piece of code more general as you can specify the exact critical section it depends on.

Comment: `how to call GetLock in thread proc`. Same answer as above. Pass it as a parameter (not nesacerily directly it can be part of another structure). But you can pass parameters when a thread is started in fact all threading code allow you to pass context.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the standard library, but do need to use `CriticalSection`s instead of whatever `std::mutex` provides, you can still make your own class that wraps a `CRITICAL_SECTION` but has the same API as `std::mutex`. That way, [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) can be used to handle the "inner RAII" part:

```
class CriticalSection {
public:
    CriticalSection() {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }

    ~CriticalSection() {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }

    void lock() {
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }

    void unlock{
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }

private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;
};
```

And use it like so:

```
CriticalSection critical_section;

int main()
{
    // No need to initialize anything anymore
    ...
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    std::lock_guard<CriticalSection> lock(criticial_section);

    // Access the shared resource.
    ...

    return 1;
}
```

If you cannot use the standard library, then I would say implement it yourself in a similar way, and that is basically what is done in Martin York's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was always wondering it if can be done this way:

```
void some_function () {
     padlock mt_guard{} ;
     // we are all alone here
     // no MT
}
```

And the padlock might be something akin to this:

```
struct padlock final {
    padlock () {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&m_CS); 
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_CS);
    }
    ~padlock () {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_CS);
        DeleteCriticalSection(&m_CS);
    }
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION    m_CS;
}
```

This might work?